# Vector space of real sequences over the field of real numbers is infinite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was going through some content on linear algebra. Meanwhile, I saw an example in which I have to show that the vector space  $\Bbb{R}^\infty$(which is basically the set of all real sequences) over the field of real numbers is not a linear span of any of its subsets i.e none of its subsets can generate it.(I feel the vague notes mean linearly independent subsets)

How do we show this?

I know that a vector space $V$ is in the linear span of its subset $S$ if every element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of any finite number of elements of $S$.

Suppose I take S={$e_1,e_2,...e_n,....$} where $e_j$ is a sequence with $1$ at the jth place and rest zero.

Now I know that this can't generate $V$ since if I take ($1,2,3,4,5$....). It can't be written as a linear combination of finite number of elements of $S$.

But this doesn't imply the non-existence of any set generating $V$.

I think we are talking about linearly independent subsets in this.

Please help how to proceed.

Comment: Notice that $S$ is linearly independent. And a basis is a maximal linearly independent system. Thus, a basis need to have at least the same cardinality as $S$.

Comment: @RicardoFreire: You mixing many thing together. $\mathbb R^\infty$ has no natural topology, so speaking about Schauder bases makes no sense. A Hamel base of a infinite dimensional Banach space is not enumerable. But obviously, there are many infinite dimensional linear space with countable bases.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong, in general I just wanted to say that every vector space has a base, excludes my previous comment.

Comment: @user251257..I have noticed that S is linearly independent. I also know that basis is a maximal linearly independent set..so from here, we just get that if $\beta$ is a basis for V, then it is linearly independent and it is the only  linearly independent subset containing itself...Now what are you saying?

Comment: @Gitika: Each pair of bases of a linear space are isomorphic, that is, they have the same cardinality (size). You could also extend $S$ to an base, as $S$ is linearly independent, so again that base has at least as "many" elements as $S$. So the dimension must be infinite (at least countable infinite).